# How to install Puppet entirely within your Home Directory?

Tags: debian, puppet, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'd like to use Puppet from Google Cloud Platform's [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/quickstart).

If you're not familiar with it, Cloud Shell is a temporary Debian instance. The only changes that persist from session to session are those that are made in the user's home directory. This means that Puppet would have to be installed entirely within the user's home directory to be available the next time the Cloud Shell was accessed.

I'm looking at Puppet's [installation guides](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/3.8/reference/install_debian_ubuntu.html) but it's not clear to me if it's possible to install Puppet completely within a user's home directory.

**Is this possible?**

Answer (score 1):

Its not a good idea to use Cloud Shell for your use case, due to the reasons mentioned on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations):

> - Non-interactive sessions will be ended automatically after a warning. Prolonged usage or computational or network intensive processes are not supported and may result in session termination without a warning.
> - If you do not access Cloud Shell regularly, we may recycle your home disk. You will receive an email notification before we do so and simply starting a session will prevent its removal.

Comment: Thanks. I understand those limitations of the Cloud Shell. I wouldn't want to use Puppet from the Cloud Shell for a Production system or anything like that. I'd simply like to try out Puppet in standalone mode and wondering whether it would be *possible* to install it in a Cloud Shell home directory so at least it's preserved from one day to the next.